# Dynamic Cell Sizing in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

After some research on Dynamic Cell Sizing in UICollection view, I think I may be in over my head working on my first iOS project. I've been looking for similar tutorials but the ones I've found are outdated and only add to my struggle when I compile and get errors because of deprecated method calls/language. I've been able to figure some out but not all and I'm at the point want I want to give up. Before I do, I wanted to ask if there is any other way of achieving this desired affect? If not, what is the current method of making cell sizes dependent on their content?

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sySKC.jpg) of what I want my layout to look like.

As you can see under Steps there is a right aligned `UILabel` next to a left aligned `multi line UILabel`. My thought process was to create a 2-column `UICollectionView` with a self-sizing cell for the right most column which sets its height based on the height of the `multi-line UILabel`, then set the height of the left most `UILabel` which contains the number to the same height as the cell to its right and continue this process till all steps are displayed.

Is my thought process correct? Will it be possible to have a cell which sizes itself to fit its content and another cell to size itself based on another's dimensions?

Comment: You will probably find it easier to do a single-column (or even a table view instead of collection view), and configure your labels (and any other visual elements) as subviews of a single cell in each "row".

Comment: Screenshot didn't work?

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll try to use a table view with two labels for each row and set the height to fit the contents. and I just found this [raywenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) which has been updated.